# Stopping an event and reinstating after animation is finished w/Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I searched and found three fairly good posts but all of them were animating at the click rather than a click sending parameters to a function that animates so neither .stop(), stop(true, true) nor event.stopPropagation() works though maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot. Thus my question.

What I am trying to prevent is the (for whatever reason) click-happy knob who clicks all the available links back and fourth rapidly and screws up the math used to calculate where a slider div/image should be. Once the animation stops, the image is off-kilter so I need to understand where to say, "Ok, something was clicked, don't allow any other clicks until the appropriate image has come into view."

Again, the difference in what I'm trying to do and what I've found is that the animation call is not happening directly under the click but rather after the click has made some calculations and sent those numbers to a different function.

I have this:

```
 $('#navs li').click(function() {
    var currentLocationNum = $('li.cs_current').index();
    var stepClicked = $(this).index();
    if (stepClicked == currentLocationNum)
       { return false;
       }
       else {
            var lftEdgeNx = $('.slidingChartHolder').position().left;
            var newLeftEdge = (stepClicked - currentLocationNum) * imageWidth;              
            moveMaster(lftEdgeNx + newLeftEdge, stepClicked);
       }
    });
```

and the moving function:

```
function moveMaster(leftEdge, newcs_current) {
    $('.slidingChartHolder').fadeTo(200, .2).animate({
        left: leftEdge
    }, "fast").fadeTo(200, 1);
    $('li.cs_current').removeClass('cs_current')
    $('li:eq('+newcs_current+')').addClass('cs_current');

      if ($('li.cs_current').index() === 0) {
            $('#previous').addClass('hideMe');
            $('#next').removeClass('hideMe');
        } else if ($('li.cs_current').index()==4){
            $('#previous').removeClass('hideMe');
            $('#next').addClass('hideMe');
                   }
        else {
            $('#previous').removeClass('hideMe');
            $('#next').removeClass('hideMe');
        }
         }
```

thanks for some insight!

Comment: It looks like this one is better using a [jsFiddle](http://jsifddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I need to understand where to say, "Ok, something was clicked, don't allow any other clicks until the appropriate image has come into view."***

I think the simple solution is to make use of jQuery's [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), which lets you test whether there is an animation in progress. So you could do this:

```
$('#navs li').click(function() {
   if ($(".slidingChartHolder").filter(":animated").length > 0)
      return;

   // your existing click code here
});
```

Alternatively, jQuery animation methods let you provide a callback function that will be executed once the animation is finished. So when starting an animation you can set a flag to indicate it is in progress and then from the callback reset that flag. Then on click test that flag and do nothing if an animation is already under way. So you could do something like this:

```
var allowClick = true;

$('#navs li').click(function() {
   if (!allowClick)
      return;

   // your existing click code here
});

function moveMaster(leftEdge, newcs_current) {
    allowClick = false;
    $('.slidingChartHolder').fadeTo(200, .2).animate({
        left: leftEdge
    }, "fast").fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
        allowClick = true;
    });

    // your existing add/remove class code here, noting that
    // adding and removing classes doesn't happen on the animation queue
}
```